# Cutting of header text in a text column

Tags: html, css, magento

My header for some reason get's cut in the top. How can i fix this.

I need to avoid such problems.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/mastervision/10xwq2zd/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.newspaper {
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-column-rule-style: outset;
    -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;


    /* Firefox */
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-rule-style: outset;
    -moz-column-rule-width: 1px;

    column-count: 2;
```

Comment: do you mean that 'FAQ - häufig gestellte Fragen' is in the first column?

Answer (score 1):

@[David K-J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4537473/david-k-j) : he mean that the 'FAQ - Häufig gestellte Fragen' is cutted.
Watch at the Screenshot, you can see that all letters are half.

@[Mastervision](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4973484/mastervision) : Can't find any problem in your fiddle, maybe they are some other *css files which are loaded later and overwriting.

Comment: Ok, hmmm. I return when i figure out why.